# Reason for 'Your connection is not private' on Chromium but not Chrome?

Tags: tls, web-browser, chrome, tls-intercept

I get this on some, but not all ssl enabled sites.

[image]

Chromium:

```
Version 53.0.2785.143 Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit)
```

Chrome:

```
Version 54.0.2840.59 (64-bit)
```

And here is the security message javascript console:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.google.fr" from accessing a frame with origin "https://clients5.google.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
```

Why is it so? How can I fix this?